# Object does not contain a definition for 'Where' ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I got one error, which I dont understand where I made mistake. 
I am trying to make function for User Login  and I used 'Where' method and I get error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)  MVCWithAngular  C:\Users\Demir\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2017\Projects\MVCWithAngular\MVCWithAngular\Controllers\DataController.cs 28  Active

**My function**

```
public JsonResult UserLogin(LoginData d)
{
    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var user = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(d.Username) && a.Password.Equals(d.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        return new JsonResult { Data = user, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

Any help how to avoid this error ?

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` directive on top of controller code, because `Where` method you want to use is a member of LINQ namespace.

Comment: What type does `dc.Users` return?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  System.Linq is alredy there, but still have a problem

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen dc.Users return a Username and Password of user

Comment: "a" username and password? So not a collection? Just 1?